# How do I clear static fragment on Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I create an app that has tabs. Each tab using static factory to instantiate the fragment. I use it so that each time the tab is loaded, my app need not to load the content again.

But, my app is able to log in and because the fragment is static, when I log out and log in as another user, the content of the fragments is of the old user, not the new one. How do I erase or make it completely remove all the content of the fragment? Right now, the solution is to kill the app and ask the user to launch the app again, but it's ugly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ditch the statics.  Ugh.  Use the built-in bundles with the activity/fragment lifecycle callbacks for state management.

Another possible solution would be to store the state of the user's login in your application class.  For all intents and purposes that is a singleton and you can be relatively certain that there will only be 1 instance of the isUserLoggedIn boolean (or whatever).  Then query the state of that boolean before displaying any content in your fragments.  That's probably the easiest means to an end.

Comment: I thought using static factory (`Fragment#newInstance()`) is the best practice for instantiate fragment. it's wrong?

Comment: You're crossing the streams.  State management and fragment creation are not the same thing.

Comment: okay, I guest I preffered to remove the static singleton. I've used `isLoggedIn`, but the content is shown from the old user is not when in a logged out condition, bt when logging in with another user after logging in with another user previously. so, checking the `isLoggedIn` will be true since the content will be shown when logged in. Thanks by the way.